# Creating plugin in qt

Tags: c++, qt

Guys from book "C++ GUI programming with qt" I'm reading a chapter on how to create your own plugin i.e. customized button. There, they mention header: #include < QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface> but in qtcreator 4.7 I'm getting error that this file does not exists. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: what header is that? Could you add the string after #include?

Comment: Which header? The information was lost.

Comment: @Johannes and freerider updated, sorry about that, this was all the time there but parsing on this website messed things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/designer-worldtimeclockplugin.html) in order to see how you should create a new designer plugin.

You need to do the following:

```
 CONFIG      += designer plugin
 TEMPLATE    = lib
```

You also have to specify the target path as following:

```
target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS]/designer
INSTALLS += target
```

Answer (score 1):

That header resides in << QtInstallDir >>/include/QtDesigner/. Have you added that directory to your include path?

Can you verify that the file exists?

Comment: I found this file on my comp in: C:\QtSDK\Simulator\Qt\mingw\include\QtDesigner

Comment: Ok, have you been able to verify that that directory is in your include path? I'm assuming that you get the error message during compilation?